# replacing CR LF in perl with "|"

Tags: perl

Using Perl, I want to replace CRLF by `|` in the end of a line beginning with `"ID"`.

So, to be more explicit: If a line begins with `"ID"`, I replace CRLF in the end of this sentence by `|`.

This is what I have done:

```
    elsif ($line =~ /^ID:\n/) { print $outputFile $line."|"; }
```

I think that it is not good ..

Comment: "I think that it is not good" — Why do you think that? Does it not behave as you expect? Or does it work and you just want a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I think that it prints | everywhere in the line and not replacing CRLF by |

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: CR LF is a space character, so why not `elsif ($line =~ /^ID:/){ $line =~  s/\s+\z/|/ }`

Comment: Thank you, did you tested what you suggest because it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @Videoretrieval Yes, It should work. Here is simple test `perl -e '$s = "ID:anytext\r"; if($s =~ /^ID:/){$s =~ s/\s+\z/|/;} print $s'`. Run it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on platform, `\n` has diffrent meanings. From [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html):

```
    LF  eq  \012  eq  \x0A  eq  \cJ  eq  chr(10)  eq  ASCII 10
    CR  eq  \015  eq  \x0D  eq  \cM  eq  chr(13)  eq  ASCII 13
             | Unix | DOS  | Mac  |
        ---------------------------
        \n   |  LF  |  LF  |  CR  |
        \r   |  CR  |  CR  |  LF  |
        \n * |  LF  | CRLF |  CR  |
        \r * |  CR  |  CR  |  LF  |
        ---------------------------
        * text-mode STDIO
```

You could do:

```
elsif ($line =~ /^(ID\b.*)\R/) { print $outputFile "$1|" }
```

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.

Comment: "`\n` is `LF` only. `CRLF` is `\r\n`." Actually the meanings of those sequences change depending on what platform you're using. See [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html) for details.

Comment: @DaveCross: You're right. I've added the reference in the answer.

Comment: Looks like that table should be updated. The "Mac" column refers to Mac OS - and no-one uses that any more.